# Как обрабатывать полученные данные

Tags: php, sql

Допустим есть данные полученные через GET

```
$objectIds = $_GET['ids];
```

и есть выборка по этим $objectIds

```
$model->exec("select * from table_name where id IN(".$objectIds.")->getAll();
```

Как правильно обрабатывать полученные данные из $_GET, может как-то фильтровать?

Comment: используйте подготовленные выражения с привязанными переменными. Эта возможность предоставляется расширениями PDO, MySQLi и другими библиотеками.

Comment: пожалуйста, можно по подробнее? мини примерчик если можно

Comment: вопрос заключается в том как защититься от sql injection или или как преобразовать  $objectIds  в нужный формат для запроса?

Comment: мне нужно обработать именно $objectIds

Comment: что имеется ввиду под обработать? Что у Вас в `$objectIds` ? Если там строка типа "1,2,3,4" то ваш пример рабочий. Другое дело если нужна защита от поддельных запросов.

Answer (score 0):

В этом запросе `$objectIds` - должно быть строкой, в которой через запятую указаны нужные вам значения `id` из таблицы `table_name`.
Все зависит от того, какой тип данных у `$objectIds`. Если это массив, тогда можете преобразовать его с помощью функции `implode(',',$objectIds);`